# How to set an environment variable in github actions

Tags: github-actions

It should be possible to update the environment variable using commands like

`echo "uploadArtifacts = '${{ inputs.uploadArtifacts}}'" >> $GITHUB_ENV`
However, it doesn't seem to be working for my example below, `run: echo ${{ env.uploadArtifacts }}` always evaluate to `false`

```yaml
name: Example
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
       runTests:
         description: run tests
         required: true
         default: true
         type: Boolean
       uploadArtifacts:
         description: upload artifacts 
         required: true
         default: true
         type: Boolean
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  
env:
  runTests: 'true'
  uploadArtifacts: 'false'

jobs:
  Build_Job:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:

    - name: Sets env vars for manual run
      if: ${{ inputs.uploadArtifacts}}
      run: |-
          echo "uploadArtifacts = '${{ inputs.uploadArtifacts}}'" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "runTests = '${{ inputs.runTests}}'" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - name: Echo uploadArtifacts 
      run: echo ${{ env.uploadArtifacts }}
```

The logs from the github actions

```
**Sets env vars for manual run**
Run echo "uploadArtifacts = 'true'" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "uploadArtifacts = 'true'" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  echo "runTests = 'false'" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    runTests: true
    uploadArtifacts: false
  
**Echo uploadArtifacts **
Run echo false
  echo false
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    runTests: true
    uploadArtifacts: false
  
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can look silly, but try removing the extra spaces inside the `echo` string, instead of:
`echo "uploadArtifacts = '${{ inputs.uploadArtifacts }}'" >> $GITHUB_ENV`
do
`echo "uploadArtifacts='${{ inputs.uploadArtifacts }}'" >> $GITHUB_ENV`.
I would also remove the quotes for the value, to make it `true` instead of `'true'`. That will convert it in a real boolean, otherwise it will be treated as a string.

Comment: also on windows we need to do $env:GITHUB_ENV